# how to handle ftp response code within bash script

Tags: bash, ftp

I am writing a bash script to do automated FTP file transfer. 
     does anyone know how to handle ftp response codes in bash script ? for example ,If I want to handle the response code 530 - Not logged in  , how can i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you use a different language with a well-tested FTP library: [Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/FTP.html), [Ruby](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/index.html), [Python](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html). These libraries will make it simpler to retrieve the response codes.

I once wrote an Expect script to do FTP automations, but then I realized I'd wasted a lot of time.